# Should we flag answers when questions are in the delete queue?

Tags: support, flags, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, self-promotion

[Python debugging tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623039/python-debugging-tips) is up for deletion:

[image]

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23922701/608639) appears to be either promotion or spam:

[image]

In any case, the answer does not provide an answer to the question of debugging tips in Python.

Should we flag answers for questions that are pending deletion?

Comment: _"Should we flag answers for questions that are pending deletion?"_ Why not?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - yes, I agree with you. But what is the site's policy and procedures covering it? What happens if the question is deleted? Does that mean some in the community cannot see the answer to properly adjudicate it? In this case, should the answer be flagged for diamond mods rather than the standard process? Or what if the site's policy is *screw it, the question is deleted*?

Comment: Not that that post is all that spammy; the user doesn't appear to be affiliated with Udacity, in any case.

Comment: @jww: If the question is deleted, the state of the answer is *moot*. It doesn't matter anymore if the answer was flagged or not.

Comment: @jww: and spam flags are handled by diamond moderators *anyway*.

Comment: @Martijn - so I'm clear (forgive my ignorance): is the *"it does not matter"* the answer? And should we read: since it does not matter, do not do it?

Comment: @jww: no, you *should* do it and not worry about what might happen to the question. Note that it'll need another 4 delete votes, and there is no queue for such posts, so it can take a while *anyway*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unless meta effect speeds it up... as in, someone posts on meta pointing to that question...

Answer (score 4):

The future state of the question should not concern you here. Focus on the answer itself, and if you feel it deserves a flag, then flag it.

If the question is deleted before the flag is handled, the flag is moot and it doesn't matter anymore, as the answer will be deleted with the question. If the question is *not* deleted the answer can be dealt with.

Note that even with 6 delete votes the question can still remain on the site for a long time; there is no review queue for delete votes, for example. People with the delete privilege would have to find it in the [moderator tools](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), and not many people are actively looking for posts to delete even there. Given the post's score it'll need a total of 10 deletion votes before it is gone.